# DependencyProperty value not getting set through data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, dependency-properties

I have a class which has a `DependencyProperty` member:

```
public class SomeClass : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeValueProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SomeValue",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(SomeClass));
            new PropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeValuePropertyChanged)));

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SomeValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public int GetSomeValue()
    {
        // This is just a contrived example.
        // this.SomeValue always returns the default value for some reason,
        // not the current binding source value
        return this.SomeValue;
    }

    private static void OnSomeValuePropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method is supposed to be called when the SomeValue property
        // changes, but for some reason it is not
    }
}
```

The property is bound in XAML:

```
<local:SomeClass SomeValue="{Binding Path=SomeBinding, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I'm using MVVM, so my viewmodel is the `DataContext` for this XAML. The binding source property looks like this:

```
public int SomeBinding
{
    get { return this.mSomeBinding; }
    set
    {
        this.mSomeBinding = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeBinding"));
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }

    return;
}
```

I'm not getting the binding source's value when I access `this.SomeValue`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I read that dependency property wrappers are bypassed by WPF at run-time, so that might explain why my breakpoints weren't being hit in the setter, but I still don't know why I can't get the value...

Comment: This looks okay from reading the code, which makes me wonder if the context is not being set up correctly.  When you run it under the debugger, do you see any data binding errors in the Output window, along the lines of "'SomeBinding' property not found on..."?

Comment: By the way, just to confirm, you are right about WPF bypassing the CLR wrapper property, and that this is why a breakpoint in the setter won't get hit.

Comment: See my answer below. I'm now trying to figure out how to bind the DataContext of a resource in a ResourceDictionary... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074321

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem was not in any of the code I shared. It turns out that my `SomeClass` instance, which I declared as a resource in my `UserControl`, was not using the same `DataContext` as the `UserControl`. I had this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SomeClass x:Key="SomeClass" SomeValue="{Binding Path=SomeBinding, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Since the `SomeClass` object didn't have the right `DataContext`, the DependencyProperty was not being set...

Comment: I was killing myself looking for this. For those of you wondering, NO the control will not simply inherit the datacontext from the userControl. Setting this.DataContext = _model is not enough. You must **explicitly** set the DataContext of the class housing the DependencyProperty as well.
    this.DataContext = _model;
    SomeClass.DataContext = _model;

Comment: OK, after several hours of figuring out what I'm talking about I understand what was happening. In my custom controls I was setting the DataContext of the entire control. That overrides any inherited DataContext. When I set the DataContext of the main Grid inside my control the DataContext of the control itself inherited fine.

Comment: WOW i cant thank you enough, i spend hours trying to figure out why this was happening. Didn't know that i had to set the data context again.