# Binding to ancestors from within a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary

How can I bind to a `UserControl`'s property from within its `ResourceDictionary`? I want an object I declare in my resources to have the same `DataContext` as the `UserControl` it is contained in:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some.Namespace"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:SomeClass
            x:Key="SomeClass"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

At runtime I get the error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'SomeClass' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Settings the DataContext directly in the code-behind works, but I'd like a XAML solution...

((SomeClass)this.Resources["SomeClass"]).DataContext = viewmodel;

Comment: I think inheritance context might have a bearing on this problem... http://blogs.msdn.com/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround was to set the `DataContext` of the resource in the code-behind.

**.xaml**

```
<local:SomeType x:Key="SomeKey" SomeProperty="{Binding ... }" />
```

**.xaml.cs**

```cs
public SomeControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ((SomeType)this.Resources["SomeKey"]).DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question (seriously).  I have never seen a XAML-only solution to this problem.  It also affects ContextMenu, MenuItem, and MenuItem.Icon.  Drives me crazy.  This seems to defeat the purpose of XAML.

Answer (score 2):

Set [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778)="False", this will clone resource on each use and make it a child of your element, enabling usage of bindings.

```
<local:SomeClass
            x:Key="SomeClass"
            x:Shared="False"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When using FindAncestor, the target element needs to be a descendent (either logical or visual) of the source. Your object does not appear in either the visual or logical tree, it's simply in the resources. So you can't use RelativeSource with FindAncestor for your object.

You can use ElementName in your Binding though. Something like this should work:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some.Namespace"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:SomeClass
            x:Key="SomeClass"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=userControl}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The binding could not find the element name using either x:Name or Name.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is just {Binding} which binds to the inherited DataContext.  Here's an example, though a bit strange shows how you can grab a color through binding to the DataContext:

```
<Window x:Class="AncestorBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Blue" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBrush}}" Content="My Button">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Unfortunately {Binding} does not work for me--Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'SomeClass' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: Have you tried not setting the DataContext at all?  I would think your local:SomeClass would inherit the DataContext from the UserControl.

Comment: I originally came across this problem because I did not set the DataContext at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073170

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create an attached behavior (ContextualizeResourceBehavior) on the user control, and specify the resource key on that attached behavior. The behavior would lookup the resource (not sure you would be able to do it on attach, if not you would need to hook up Loaded event) and transfer the data context.

Answer (score 0):

when you add your resource to the visual tree it should inherit the data context. but... have a look at [element spy](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/) it might just do what you need.